# C++ Vector weird behaviour

Tags: c++, vector

I have this piece of code which iterates over a directory, gets the filenames and pushes them in a vector.

```
std::vector<const char*> afp_filenames;
if ((dir = opendir (path.c_str())) != NULL) {
  while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
    if ( (ent->d_name[0] == '.') ) continue;
    afp_filenames.push_back((const char*)ent->d_name);
    cout <<afp_filenames[i]<<"\n";
    i++;
  }
}
```

cout prints the correct filenames. The issue comes afterwards when I print again the values stored in the vector. I get the same result when using an iterator.

```
for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    cout <<afp_filenames[j]<<"\n";
}
```

Here is a sample of what I get in the console.
for the first loop:

```
afp_PortaAPorta_5_318_383.dat
afp_PortaAPorta_5_407_663.dat
afp_PortaAPorta_5_485_510.dat
afp_781_5_472_371.dat
afp_781_5_115_617.dat
afp_781_5_358_509.dat
afp_781_5_276_348.dat
```

and for the second one:

```
2.dat
.dat
afpò
9.dat
2.dat
5_356_572.dat
5_291_435.dat
afp_781_5_243_558.dat

afp_PortaAPorta_5_352_716.dat

afp_781_5_111_541.dat
```

Comment: Probably you just need to copy the string as the pointer you get from d_name may end up being garbage some time later.

Comment: @gd1 ... just my thought.
Use `std::string` as the element type instead.

Comment: While the question isn't "brilliant" I don't think it's worth downvoting or closing. Can you guys elaborate?

Comment: Many problems will simply disappear by using `std::vector` and `std::string`. You are half way there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are storing `const char *`s in the vector but the pointers are no longer valid by the time you get to the second loop and so `cout` is trying to print out whatever is left in the memory they were pointing to.

From [readdir](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir):

> On success, readdir() returns a pointer to a dirent structure. (This structure may be statically allocated; do not attempt to free(3) it.)

The lifetime of the struct returned by the system call seems to be managed by the <s>kernel</s> C library.

Answer (score 4):

You are storing `const char *` pointers pointing to memory returned by `readdir`.

Per [`man 3 readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir):

> The data returned by readdir() may be overwritten by subsequent calls to readdir() for the same directory stream.

Therefore, your `ent->d_name` entries are being overwritten each loop.

Use a `vector<std::string>` instead so that you store *copies* of the string (as an added benefit, you won't have to worry about allocating/deallocating the strings since it will be handled for you).

Answer (score 2):

Probably you just need to copy the string as the pointer you get from `d_name` may end up pointing to garbage or something else some time later. Make a vector of `std::string`s and push strings into it.